# Can Julia to connect to S3/Athena and use SQL?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, julia

Is it possible run a SQL-esque script to pull data within Julia from AWS's S3/Athena? My Julia instance is located on AWS Sagemaker Jupyter Notebook.

Using python in SageMaker easily enough:

```
import boto3
region = boto3.Session().region_name

from pyathena import connect
import pandas as pd

conn = connect(s3_staging_dir='s3://sagemaker-examplebucket/',
               region_name = region)

df = pd.read_sql("""SELECT 
 something1,
 something2
FROM "customer_data"."sagemaker_data"
WHERE 
    something = 0;""", conn)
```

For my instance of SageMaker Notebook using Julia I can connect and put/get an existing file, but I can't find anything that allows new queries like Python's pyathena library:

```
using AWS, AWSS3, Serialization
struct SampleData
  a::Int
  b::String
end

d=SampleData(1,"sss")
aws = global_aws_config(; region="us-west-2")
b = IOBuffer()
serialize(b, d)

s3_put(aws, "sagemaker-examplebucket","myfile.bin", b.data)

ddat = s3_get(aws, "sagemaker-examplebucket","myfile.bin")
d2 = deserialize(IOBuffer(ddat))

@assert d == d2
```

Comment: This looks like Athena. Athena has ODBC drivers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-odbc.html so you could connect to it like any other SQL database using ODBC.jl for example.

Comment: However, I am using AWS's Julia Jupyter lab. These ODBC drivers are mainly for local connections to Athena/S3.

I found the way to connect to S3 but I cannot seem to form queries in Athena like I can with python's pyathena library...

Comment: If you do `@service Athena` then you have access to these API functions: https://github.com/JuliaCloud/AWS.jl/blob/master/src/services/athena.jl. Eg `Athena.start_query_execution`